# Get all of child nodes in a hierarchical data in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have the following sql table:

```
id   parent_id
1    null
2    1
3    4
4    8
5    1
6    2
7    6
8    null
```

How can i get all of child nodes of some specific node?
For example with id = 1:

```
1 2 5 6 7
```

with id = 8

```
8 4 2
```

Comment: What database platform??

Comment: any common rdbms platform, sql or pgSQL

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out in another blog, hope it will help other people:

```
with RECURSIVE cte(id,parent_id) as (
  select
    id,
    parent_id
  from forum
  where id = 2
  UNION ALL
  select
    forum.id,
    forum.parent_id
  from forum
    inner join cte on forum.parent_id = cte.id
)
select * from cte
```